# Dialog Box containing Map opens only first time in Android?

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-layout

Currently, I am working with map Api. I need to show a recyclerview and map view in a dialog box. When I click on a button i.e.; btnDialog in activity, then a dialog layout opens which contains 2 buttons. First for Map i.e.; btnMap and other for verify service call i.e.; btnVerify button. If I click on btnMap then the current dialog closes and another dialog opens containing map fragment and recyclerview list.

Now, the problem which I am facing is that when I click on the (button) btnDialog of activity. Then the dialog containing the 2 buttons opens. Now, if I click on (button) btnMap to open mapview, then this dialog closes and other dialog opens which contains map fragment as well as recyclerview list. Then I close this map dialog and whenever i again click on btnMap to open dialog containing map, then it is throwing an exception,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #80: Duplicate id 0x7f0e00ee, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

I searched for it and apply all possible solutions but didn't get any result to solve this. 2nd dialog opens only one time. If I restart that particular activity then map dialog opens first time again.

Is it require to use DialogFragment? Then how to use it?

Comment: share your code and XML file